# Error using method page

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm get an error with method page using Capybara With Ruby.

Error message "undefined local variable or method `page' for # (NameError)".

```
Então(/^devo visualizar a pagina diagnostico hospitalar$/) do
expect(page).to have_content 'Diagnostico'
```

end

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec and Capybara undefined local variable or method \`page'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448012/rspec-and-capybara-undefined-local-variable-or-method-page)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using cucumber, in which case your error would mean Capybara::DSL hasn't been included in the the Cucumber "World".  Make sure you're using the gem cucumber-rails (if a rails project) or have followed the instructions in the Capybara README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber